# C# SQLite Connector Problems

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Given the code :

```
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE \"Category\" SET \"name\"=?name, \"description\"=?description, \"color\"=?color, \"active\"=?active, \"parent\"=?parent WHERE \"id\"=?id", sql);  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?id", DbType.Int32).Value = _id;  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?name", DbType.String).Value = _name;  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?description", DbType.String).Value = _description;  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?color", DbType.Int32).Value = _color;  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?active", DbType.Boolean).Value = _active;  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?parent", DbType.Int32).Value = _parent;  
        cmd.Prepare();  
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

We have the problem that the last line throws

```
SQLite error  near "name": syntax error
```

which IMO is nonsense. Something else must be going on. The table is connected and open (as I can read from the table just fine) and everything else works just great. It just can't seem to handle this simple update for some reason.

EDIT: OK. I tried taking the name field out entirely and still no dice. I just get the error on the description field then. It's definitely not a keyword issue.

Comment: Have you tried changing the named parameter from name to something else? Could it be a keyword issue?

Comment: @Kevin Hsu I tried renaming it to zname still with the same error.

Comment: Do you need to supply the Size property for the string? Whose provider are you using?

Comment: @Tim I tried it with the size property, still the same problem. The provider is the System.Data.SQLite from [http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", DbType.Int32);  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", DbType.String);  
...

cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = _id;  
cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = _name;  
...
```

Comment: Bam. ?parameter is the way the MySQL connector likes it. The SQLite connector does it @parameter with an @ instead of a ?.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets around field names in the sql syntax, as they can conflict with reserved words too. Brackets will eliminate this problem. I am not sure but both id and name could be reserved words.

Comment: Even without the name field it just says  it has the the problem with description then.